# How to hide parent element by clicking on child button in jQuery

Tags: jquery, show-hide, jquery-events

I have following HTML code and I want to hide div with class editfield and editfieldlink link and show div with class value. I tried following jQuery code it did not work for me, but this works fine if I hide a parent like this statement: `$(this).closest('div.editfield').parent().hide();`

```
<tr class="row-fluid settingsrow">
                <td class="span2">
                    <strong>Name</strong>
                </td>
                
                <td class="span8">
                <div class="value">ALI ASAD</div>
                <div class="editfield">
                    <form class="form-vertical">         
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label">First Name</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="Ali">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Last Name</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Asad">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <div class="controls">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-mini">Save Changes</button>
                                <button class="btn btn-inverse btn-mini cancelactionsettings">Cancel</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form> 
                </div>
                </td>
                <td class="span1"><a href="#" class="editfieldlink" style="text-decoration:none"><small>Edit</small></a></td>
            </tr>
```

And my JavaScript is like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) 
    {
    $('#settingseditor .cancelactionsettings').click(function(event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();

        $(this).closest('div.editfield').hide();
        $(this).closest('div.value').show();
        $(this).closest('a.editfieldlink').hide();
        
    });
    
});
```

Comment: Where is the element with id="settingseditor"?

Comment: @GeorgeBoot It's obviously a parent that is further up the DOM than the `<tr>` that he has shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just aren't traversing correctly

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $('#settingseditor .cancelactionsettings').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('div.editfield').hide();
        $(this).closest('div.editfield').prev('.value').show(); // .value is a prev sibling of div.editfield
        $(this).closest('td').next().find('a.editfieldlink').hide();// anchor is in the next sibling td
    });
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6EfMj/)

Comment: Thanks brother. Actually I was also assigning event handler to the parent div which was inherited to this button so this was not working good.

Answer (score 1):

try parents().

```
$('#settingseditor .cancelactionsettings').click(function(event)
{
  event.preventDefault();

  $(this).parents('div.editfield').hide();
  $(this).parents('div.editfield').prev().show();
  $(this).parents('td.span8').next().find('a.editfieldlink');

});
```

**note: i didn't find `#settingseditor` in your code....if incase , you are trying to use multiselecter then, you forgot `,` operator there...**

```
$('#settingseditor , .cancelactionsettings').click(...
 //---------------^^^^--- here
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where the element with id `#settingseditor` lives, but it works for me if I am looking for just the `.cancelactionsettings` element

```
$('#settingseditor, .cancelactionsettings').click(function(event)
{
   ...
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/78zKZ/1)

Answer (score 0):

Your selector doesn't match any element ; change this `$('#settingseditor .cancelactionsettings')` to `$('.cancelactionsettings')`.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XBpAN/) for a working example